# How to return a php variable in ajax callback and use it?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am send a ajax request to php file where i will update the database and and i will select a value according to my condition. But how to return that $variable in ajax callback and show it in input text box.

```
$.ajax({
    url:'updatenewuser.php',
    data: {
        bookid: bookid,
        id: 2,
        startdate: cal
    }, // pass data 
    success:function(data) {    
    }
});
```

my PHP file is

```
<?php
$conn = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'root') or die("error connecting1...");
mysql_select_db("cubitoindemo",$conn) or die("error connecting database...");
if($_GET['id']==2) //taking
{
    $book_id = $_GET['bookid'];
    $startdate = $_GET['startdate'];
    $update_validity = "UPDATE booking SET valid = '2',start_date_timestamp = '$startdate' where book_id = '$book_id'";
    $query = mysql_query($update_validity);
    if($query==TRUE)
    {
        $get_select_query = "select start_date_timestamp from booking where book_id = '$book_id'";
        $get_query = mysql_query($get_select_query);
        $row = mysql_fetch_assoc(get_query);
        $startdate_return = $row['start_date_timestamp'];
        echo $startdate_return;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: can we see how you make request and what you return from php code.?

Comment: Please post your PHP code.

Comment: why not return the value of PHP variable and assign it to a JS variable to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an element in your page like `<span>` and give it a unique ID like `<span id="testspan"></span>`. This is where the text gets displayed. Then in your JS;

```
$.ajax({
    url:'updatenewuser.php',
    data: {
        bookid: bookid,
        id: 2,
        startdate: cal
    }, // pass data 
    success:function(result) { 
      $( "#testspan" ).html(result);   
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use json format like:

**in your php file**

```
$arrFromDb = array(
'id' => 1,
'bookName' => 'Da Vinci Code'
)

echo json_encode( $arrFromDb ); exit();
```

**in you script**

```
$.ajax({
    url:'updatenewuser.php',
    data: {
        bookid: bookid,
        id: 2,
        startdate: cal
    }, // pass data 
    success:function(data) {  
        var book = $.parseJSON(data) // now book is a javascript object
        var bookName = book.bookName; 
    }
});
```

I hope this will help you

Comment: i am not using your method but now i got to know that i can user json too.. thanks @Cristian

Comment: This is the best solution when you say you want to use specific variables from php page

Answer (score 1):

Just `echo` in your php file, the output (instead of being shown by the browser as a default PHP page) will be usable in the JS as the result of the ajax call (`data`)

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [val()](http://api.jquery.com/val),

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" id="inputId" />
```

**Js**

```
$.ajax({
    url:'updatenewuser.php',
    data: {
        bookid: bookid,
        id: 2,
        startdate: cal
    }, // pass data 
    success:function(data) {   
         $( "#inputId" ).val(data); 
    }
});
```

**PHP CODE**

```
<?php
   echo $bookid= isset($_REQUEST['bookid']) ? $_REQUEST['bookid'] : "No bookid";
   // you can use $_GET for get method and $_POST for post method of ajax call
   return
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

**In updatenewuser.php**

```
//after all operations 

echo $variable_to_pass;
```

Then in the ajax request :

```
$.ajax({
    url:'updatenewuser.php',
    data: {
        bookid: bookid,
        id: 2,
        startdate: cal
    }, // pass data 
    success:function(result) { 
        alert(result);//result will be the value of variable returned.  
        $("#input_box").val(result);  //jquery
        document.getElementById("input_box").value = result; // Javascript way

    }
});
```

HTML being  :

```
<input type="text" id="input_box" value=""/>
```

Cheers